# Can't add keyframes properly

Tags: keyframes

I am very inexperienced so if the solution is simple no hate please. I am trying to add more keyframes but it says: F-Curve with path= 'location'(2) cannot be keyframed. Ensure it is not locked or sampled. Also, try removing F-Modifiers.

I have no idea what this means. Can someone please explain it to me? I'd greatly appreciate it thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you add more information about what are you trying to achieve? Your scene setup, relations between objects, properties you can't keyframe...

Comment: Please edit your question showing the context in which this is happening. A .blend file to inspect would be the easiest way to find out what's going on.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but you can 'solve' the issue by right clicking on the 'animation' data in the Outliner, right click and select 'Clear Animation Data'.

Answer (score 3):

In the Animation layout there is a "Dope Sheet" and summary. I resolved this problem by unchecking the lock icon.

[image]

This was my error:

> RuntimeError: Error: F-Curve with path 'scale[2]' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers

After turning the lock icon off it works!